# Route concatenation with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having a problem with React Router and a paging. If I am at the root of the project and I click on the next button, it will go to mydomain.com/page/2 and so on. This is correct.

But if I am in mydomain.com/categories when I click next it goes to mydomain.com/page/2 but then if I give previous or next it begins to concatenate the routes in the form mydomain.com/page/2/page/1 / page / 2 and so on.

So are the routes:

```
<Route path="/categoria/:id/:slug/page/:page" exact>
  <Category />
</Route>
<Route path="/categoria/:id/:slug">
  <Category />
</Route>
```

To my pagination component I pass as props the current url, the array of products brought from the api, the current page and the number of pages:

```
<Pagination baseurl={`${urlActual}/`} pagina={pagina} productos={productsByTag} pageCount={pageCount}/>
```

As for the links of the buttons within the pagination component, they are made in the following way:

```
pagina ? (
    <Link to={`${baseUrl}page/${Number(pagina)+1}`}>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </Link>
  ):(
    <Link to={`${baseUrl}page/2`}>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Prev</button>
    </Link>
   )
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Where is `urlActual` coming from?

Comment: Yes, please include how you are computing your `baseUrl`, AKA `urlActual`. You appear to be simply prepending your current URL.

Comment: I'm getting it in the following way: useLocation().pathname;

Comment: I had to add that parameter because otherwise I was directed to the root path

Comment: So, if the `pathname` is "/page/1" is the `urlActual`/`baseUrl`, and you `to={`${baseUrl}page/2`}` what do you think the pushed path will be?

Comment: What you say is correct. The problem is that I need to use the paging component both in root and in any other directory. That is why I had raised the option of the base url, but now that you tell me it makes sense. Can you think of any way that the component works both from root and from any other directory?

Comment: Extra prop specifying if "root" or not?

Comment: Sorry, but this is new for me...If not root how should the Link route be composed? Because if I pass the link to the page directly it sends me to root/page/2 and I only need "page / 2" to be added to the current url. Thanks in advance